# Elasticsearch : Error when trying to clear scroll

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, elasticsearch, nestjs

I would like to do a clearScroll after a query because I have this error :

`Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: [500]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_open_scroll_context] setting"`

So I do my scroll query, it works and at the end I call

`await this.client.clearScroll({ scroll_id : scrollId })`

And I got :

```
`ResponseError: {"succeeded":true,"num_freed":0}
    at Unzip.onBody [as cb] (C:\Work\distrib-api\node_modules\@elastic\elasticsearch\lib\Transport.js:367:23)
    at Unzip.zlibBufferOnEnd (node:zlib:161:10)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  meta: {
    body: { succeeded: true, num_freed: 0 },
    statusCode: 404,
    headers: {
      'x-elastic-product': 'Elasticsearch',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-length': '57',
      'set-cookie': [Array]
    },
    meta: {
      context: null,
      request: [Object],
      name: 'elasticsearch-js',
      connection: [Object],
      attempts: 0,
      aborted: false
    }
  }
}`
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot.